# WFS queries data through time field in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs

Now using ol4.6.5, GeoServer uses 2.17.2, the following error appears

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Filter:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function During Parsing
> failed for Filter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function
> During Unable to find function During

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please fix your first question rather than delete and repost exactly the same question